# How would I calculate the numerical value of this integral / function in python?

Tags: integration, computational-mathematics

I am trying compute numerically the value of this function:

$ F(x) = x \, \int_x^{+\infty} K_{5/3} (z) \, dz $

Where $ K_{5/3} (z) $ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind and of order $ \frac{5}{3} $. This is the only thing I've been able to come up with:

```
from scipy.special import kv
from scipy.integrate import trapezoid
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

K = kv(5/3, np.linspace(0.1, 10, 1000))

F = []
for x in np.linspace(0, 10, 1000):
    F.append(x * trapezoid(K, np.linspace(x, 100, 1000)))
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 10, 1000), F)
```

The result is certainly incorrect. The plot should look like the diagrams in [page 23 of this pdf](https://www.astro.umd.edu/%7Erichard/ASTR480/Beckmann_Longair_Radiation2.pdf), shown both in linear and logarithmic axes.

I really can't come up with anything else. I think the problem might be that the upper limit in python is not $ +\infty $, but I have found no way to implement integration with infinite limits in python. Any help?

Comment: You may use $$
\int_x^{ + \infty } {K_\nu  (z){\rm d}z}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - x\cosh t} \frac{{\cosh (\nu t)}}{{\cosh t}}{\rm d}t} .
$$ An asmptotic expansion for large values of $x$ is given in section 2.5 on page 53 of *Integrals of Bessel Functions* by Yudell L. Luke.

Answer (score 1):

I shall give you the analytical solution is order you be able to check your calculations.

$$F(x)=x \left(\frac{27 \sqrt{3} \pi  x^{8/3} \,
   _1F_2\left(\frac{4}{3};\frac{7}{3},\frac{8}{3};\frac{x^2}{4}\right)}{160\ 2^{2/3}
   \Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)}-\frac{2^{2/3} \sqrt{3} \pi  \,
   _1F_2\left(-\frac{1}{3};-\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3};\frac{x^2}{4}\right)}{x^{2/3}
   \Gamma \left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)}-\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$

Being blind (and then unable to produce even decent plots), I just give you below  a table to check your results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x & F(x) \\
 0.00 & 0.000000 \\
 0.25 & 0.915800\\
 0.50 & 0.870819 \\
 0.75 & 0.765267 \\
 1.00 & 0.651423 \\
 1.25 & 0.544867 \\
 1.50 & 0.450640 \\
 1.75 & 0.369775 \\
 2.00 & 0.301636 \\
 2.25 & 0.244926 \\
 2.50 & 0.198145 \\
 2.75 & 0.159812 \\
 3.00 & 0.128566 \\
 3.25 & 0.103203 \\
 3.50 & 0.082687 \\
 3.75 & 0.066140 \\
 4.00 & 0.052827 \\
 4.25 & 0.042139 \\
 4.50 & 0.033574 \\
 4.75 & 0.026722 \\
 5.00 & 0.021248
\end{array}
\right)$$